# What's the standard way of executing JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

<sub>This question [had been asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615902/standard-way-of-running-javascript-code), but was closed down by trolls. My attempts to reopen have failed, so I ask the same question again, providing a useful answer along with it.</sub>

What is the standard procedure for running Javascript code? I am learning JavaScript but my tutorial has nothing to say about how to run the code.

Do people normally write their code in a text editor and paste to a browser console?

Comment: Explain the downvotes?

Comment: What's the point in this question/answer pair? There isn't a specific programming problem presented, and the information in your answer can be found in numerous other places on the internet. It might help if you made this question community wiki but I'd still question it's value. Also, FWIW your previous question was closed for good reason and not by trolls

Comment: I believe this could be a good canonical question, +1 for the effort.

Comment: There is value here, the question is very much javascript specific and the answer provided gives a great insight for beginners into how javascript can be used beyond the 'normal' browser dependent method. The downvotes IMO are unwarranted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard way of running Javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615902/standard-way-of-running-javascript-code)

Comment: @Bojangles I see your point and it is quite amusing you'd post that. Despite this, the answer here is more valuable than the closed dupe you've posted.

Comment: @Bojangles Seriously? Running code is not a programming problem?? And I'm sure that most of the information on SO can be found in other places on the internet. Are you sure you're not trolling?

Comment: This types of questions on SO are deprecated. You can make it community wiki to help people who are very^6 beginner to javascript rather than getting reputation from your answer and questoins.

Comment: @C-linkNepal What dou you mean, deprecated? Can you give more information on that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Pumbaa80 No, I am not trolling. You keep using that word, and I don't think it means what you think it means. Running code can be a programming problem, but asking what the standard/most common procedure for running said code is an opinionated topic

Comment: Excellent question, excellent answer - +1.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard way of running JavaScript code.

A little bit of background:

JavaScript [was originally](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript) designed to run in a browser. Back in the old days, JS development was painful. You'd have to mix a lot of `alert`s into your code and pray that you'd somehow find the relevant information. Then, hit F5 in your browser and wait until something pops up. Later, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) came along, providing an interactive console and decent debugger. Everybody used it, there was no alternative. Browser vendors nowadays have caught up and included useful debugging tools in the browser itself.

Also, several JavaScript execution environments and a ton of tools have emerged. You're free to use any of them, but your choice will most likely depend on your code.

Basically, these are your options:

#### Run in a browser

If you need a [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and thus a `document`, or other browser-specific objects like `alert`, you should run your code in a browser. If you're not sure what I'm talking about, then you also should use this method.

Either

- Create a HTML file on your computer and

  - put your script directly inside: `<script>alert('Hello world')</script>` (quick'n'dirty method), or
  - create a separate JS file and include it like so: `<script src="myscript.js"></script>`

Then, open the HTML file in the browser of your choice.

Or

- Use an online service like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/), or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/). Such services provide an easy way to share your code with others.

Or

- Enter your code in the browser console. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE and Chrome (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for Chrome/Mac), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇪</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in Firefox (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for FF/Mac), and put your code into the console. Hit <kbd>⏎</kbd> to run it or <kbd>⇪</kbd>+<kbd>⏎</kbd> for a line break.

  This method is mainly suitable if you have very little code and don't want to save it.

<sub>Arguably, Chrome's DevTools offer the most advanced features, while IE's F12 tools are far behind every other browser.</sub>

- A little-known alternative is [Firefox's Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad), which can be opened by <kbd>⇪</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This was designed for entering larger code snippets and offers extended features like Open and Save.

#### Run in the command line

If you don't need any HTML document (say, for example, you want to program a Fibonacci number generator with no UI), you may resort to a command-line tool like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). There are other alternatives like [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Rhino), but nowadays, Node.js is the most popular and most sophisticated tool available.

- Save your code to a file, then open a Terminal or [Command Prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window), and enter `node myprogram.js`. Use `console.log` to produce output.

Or

- Run `node` and enter your code interactively like in a browser console.

#### Advanced method: Run a *"headless"* browser (with no GUI)

I mention this for completeness' sake. Do not use this unless you have some experience with JS.

You can actually run a browser within a console. No User Interface there, everything runs in the dark, but it's a real browser. I'm talking about [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is primarily used for automated testing. If you know what I'm talking about, you probably have enough experience to make me wonder why you are reading this anyway. Again, this is an advanced method. Beginners, move along!

#### Run in the IDE

Modern IDEs may come with a JS engine/debugger. There is no standard IDE* for JS development, so refer to the manuals of your favourite IDE for more information.

*<sub>Inspiration for your search: WebStorm, NetBeans, Eclipse, Sublime Text, ...</sub>